# Mechanisms for timed delivery of NMIs

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, x86-64, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I would like a timed delivery of a non-maskable interrupt (NMI). Specifically, I would like to be able to put the processor into a C state with interrupts disabled. Then, I expect the processor to wake up on delivery of the NMI.

I know that performance counters can be setup to deliver NMIs on overflow. However, I am not sure what event the counters should be setup to count. You can't count instructions or unhalted clock cycles because the CPU is basically halted.

I realize that you might not want to do this on a deployed system but this is more for an academic experiment. I want to be able to control the precise amount of time spent in the sleep state.